# Atualizar tela no react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, mongodb, sql-update, atualização

Estou com uma dúvida aqui e preciso da ajuda de vocês, por favor.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em react native e surgiu a seguinte necessidade:

Estou na tela A e redireciono para a tela B através do props.navigation.navigate. Nesta tela B é feita uma alteração no banco de dados e em seguida, retorno para a tela A.

O problema é que neste retorno para a tela A os dados não são recarregados, uma vez que os componentes já estão montados.

Ou seja, como voltar para uma tela anterior renderizando novamente os componentes, já que as informações no banco de dados foram modificadas.

Tentei utilizar o componentDidUpdate mas não consegui, pois fica ocorrendo estouro de memória.

Aqui um trecho de código da tela A, onde é chamado no componentDidUpdate o getDisciplines(), uma função responsável em buscar do banco de dados as informações que foram atualizadas na tela B:

```
async componentDidUpdate() {
        this.getDisciplines();
    }

    getDisciplines = async () => {
        try {
            this.setState({ isLoading: true });
            const { _id } = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@APP:user'));
            const { data } = (await Api.post('/questionnaire/findAllByPeriod',
                { idStudent: _id }));
            const { questionnairesByPeriod } = data
            if (questionnairesByPeriod !== null) {
                this.setState({ questionnairesByPeriod });
            }
            this.props.navigation.setParams({ load: false });
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

Aqui o trecho de código da tela B que atualiza as informações no banco e redireciona para a tela A:

```
saveState = async () => {
        try {
            const { question_answer, commentary } = this.state;
            const { idQuestionnaire } = question_answer[0];
            const list = {
                idQuestionnaire,
                commentary,
                status: 'I',
                questionAnswer: question_answer
            }
            const response = await Api.put('/questionnaire/update', list)
            this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenSelectionDisciplines')
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

Desde já agradeço o apoio.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Em seu código, sua tela B está chamando a API que é uma operação assíncrona e logo em seguida você já chama o navigation indo para a tela A que é se não me engano é uma operação síncrona, isso provavelmente é o seu problema. Por convenção, sua tela A deveria chamar a API pra buscar os dados através do componentDidMount/useEffect mesmo, é bem usado esse Lifecycle pra esse tipo de situação.

Em resumo, quando você na tela B chama a API que é uma operação assíncrona, esse processo acaba demorando algum tempo pra ser executado, vamo usar de exemplo 2 segundos. Porém, quando você navega para a tela A novamente você chega lá em menos de 1 segundo e a operação de chamada em sua API não se concluiu e você chega na tela A antes da resposta a sua API chegar.

Além de usar o componentDidMount/useEffect na tela A, você deveria aguardar a resposta da API na tela B pra depois prosseguir para a tela A fazendo uma validação para aguardar a execução da Promise na chamada a API.

Por exemplo:

```
const response = await Api.put('/questionnaire/update', list)
if (response) this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenSelectionDisciplines')
```

Vejo também que a situação pode ocorrer na sua função *getDisciplines()* e isso pode influenciar sua exibição dependendo das suas validações em cima do *isLoading*. Veja estas suas linhas de código:

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({ load: false });
this.setState({ isLoading: false });
```

Provavelmente o mesmo cenário pode acontecer nestas linhas, pois quando você chama a API que é uma operação assíncrona, elas não foram incluídas dentro do escopo de tratamento da Promise:

```
if (questionnairesByPeriod !== null) { 
  // Aqui 
}
```

Isso pode fazer com que seu *isLoading* e o seu Parâmetro de navegação *load* recebam o valor *false* antes mesmo da chamada a API se concretizar, logo teríamos a mesma situação. Talvez este caso possa acontecer e ser imperceptível, pois a execução da linha dentro do escopo do tratamento da Promise:

```
this.setState({ questionnairesByPeriod });
```

Iria disparar uma nova renderização em tela com os valores retornados pela API, isso pode ser muito rápido que talvez seja imperceptível, mas provavelmente acontece.

Recomendo você dar uma estudada melhor em como de fato funciona o Lifecycle do React, isso pode te ajudar bastante em suas construções de código usando o ecossistema.

Um abraço!